# Image resize is not happening with dynamic image table with Javascript in IE8

Tags: javascript, image, dynamic, internet-explorer-8, resize

Actual called images are of size of 2000x2000 approx, when I want them to be 165x165 they are not changing. `displayed[i]` has part names as it is in first row and their respective images are called in second row. `img.setAttribute` thing is also given try.
Is only having CSS with Javascript the way for this?

Javascript:

```
var divT = document.getElementById("tableHolder");
    var tb1 = document.createElement('table'),
        row,
        cell,
        i;
    tb1.cellSpacing="0";
    tb1.border="1";
    tb1.width="180";
    row = tb1.insertRow(-1);
    for (i = 0; i < p; i++) {
    cell = row.insertCell(i);
    cell.innerHTML= displayed[i];
        }
    row = tb1.insertRow(-1);
    for (i = 0; i < p; i++) {
    cell = row.insertCell(i);
    img = new Image();
    img.src = 'Part_database/' + displayed[i] + '.jpg';
    img.width="165";
    img.height="165";
    cell.appendChild(img);
    }
    divT.appendChild(tb1);
```

HTML:

```
<div id="tableHolder"></div>
```

Comment: img.style.width="165";
img.style.height="165";
this is working..Thanks anyways...